# route.params has properties that don't match dynamic url

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to ask about vue-router. This is my first time using vue js.

Initially I was on the route:

> **localhost: 8080 / article / edit-article / 2**

and when I move to route:

> **localhost: 8080 / page**

this is still running.

But when I moved from:

> **localhost: 8080 / article / edit-article / 2**

to:

> **locahost: 8080 / dashboard**

the route instead changed to:

> **localhost: 8080 / article / edit-article / dashboard**

not:

> **localhost: 8080 / dashboard**

This my vue-router:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  linkActiveClass: 'open active',
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/login',
      name: 'Home',
      component: DefaultContainer,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          name: 'Dashboard',
          component: Dashboard,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          }
        },
        {
          path: 'page',
          name: 'Page',
          component: Page,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/article',
      component: DefaultContainer,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'List Articles',
          component: Article,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          }
        },
        {
          path: 'add-article',
          name: 'Add Article',
          component: AddArticle,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          }
        },
        {
          path: 'edit-article/:id',
          name: 'Edit Article',
          component: EditArticle,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        requiresVisitor: true
      }
    },
  ]
})
```

I use navbar with js, like this:

```
export default {
  items: [
    {
      name: 'Dashboard',
      url: 'dashboard',
      icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    },
    {
      name: 'Article',
      url: 'article',
      icon: 'icon-note'
    },
    {
      name: 'Page',
      url: '/page',
      icon: 'icon-layers'
    },   
  ]
}
```

and this my `DefaultContainer`:

```
<template>   
<div class="app">
    <AppHeader fixed>
      <SidebarToggler class="d-lg-none" display="md" mobile />
      <b-link class="navbar-brand" to="/dashboard">
        <img class="navbar-brand-full" src="img/brand/logo.svg" width="89" height="25">
        <img class="navbar-brand-minimized" src="img/brand/sygnet.svg" width="30" height="30>
      </b-link>
      <SidebarToggler class="d-md-down-none" display="lg" />
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
        <DefaultHeaderDropdownAccnt/>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </AppHeader>
    <div class="app-body">
      <AppSidebar fixed>
        <SidebarHeader/>
        <SidebarForm/>
        <SidebarNav :navItems="nav"></SidebarNav>
        <SidebarFooter/>
        <SidebarMinimizer/>
      </AppSidebar>
      <main class="main">
        <Breadcrumb :list="list"/>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
      </main>
      <AppAside fixed>
        <!--aside-->
        <DefaultAside/>
      </AppAside>
    </div>
    <TheFooter>
      <!--footer-->
      <div>
        <span class="ml-1">&copy; 2019 local Incorporation. All Rights Reserved</span>
      </div>
    </TheFooter>   
</div> 
</template>

<script> 
import nav from '@/_nav' 
import { Header as AppHeader, SidebarToggler,` `Sidebar as AppSidebar, SidebarFooter, SidebarForm, SidebarHeader, SidebarMinimizer, SidebarNav, Aside as AppAside, AsideToggler, Footer as TheFooter, Breadcrumb } from '@coreui/vue' 
import DefaultAside from './DefaultAside' 
import DefaultHeaderDropdown from './DefaultHeaderDropdown'`

export default {
  name: 'DefaultContainer',
  components: {
    AsideToggler,
    AppHeader,
    AppSidebar,
    AppAside,
    TheFooter,
    Breadcrumb,
    DefaultAside,
    DefaultHeaderDropdown,
    SidebarForm,
    SidebarFooter,
    SidebarToggler,
    SidebarHeader,
    SidebarNav,
    SidebarMinimizer
  },
  data () {
    return {
      nav: nav.items
    }   
  },   
  computed: {
    name () {
      return this.$route.name
    },
    list () {
      return this.$route.matched.filter((route) => route.name || route.meta.label )
    }   
  }
} 
</script>
```

Thanks all

Comment: How did you move from `localhost:8080/article/edit-article/2` to `locahost:8080/dashboard`? Was it via JS code or a `router-link`? Could you include that code. It sounds like you've just got a relative path problem.

Comment: Use js code in vue router

Comment: That isn't what I meant. The code in the question is just your router config. That tells us what pages exist but it doesn't show how you are moving from one page to another. We need to see the code you're using to navigate between the routes. It might involve a `<router-link>` tag in your template. Or perhaps you're using the JavaScript API, e.g. `router.push(...)`?

Comment: yes i use router.push in article table if go to edit article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that the problem is here:

```js
url: 'dashboard',
```

This would appear to be a relative path. So if you are currently on the page `http://localhost:8080/article/edit-article/2` it will resolve relative to that URL, giving `http://localhost:8080/article/edit-article/dashboard`. This isn't really anything to do with Vue router, it's just how relative URLs are resolved. You'd get exactly the same behaviour if you used an HTML link such as `<a href="dashboard">`.

If you start your relative URL with a `/` then it will omit the rest of the path:

```js
url: '/dashboard',
```

This should fix your problem. This is what you've done with your `/page` URL, which is presumably why that works.

Personally I would use named routes instead, rather than trying to craft relative URLs. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html